# Control a C# application from a Public Webpage

Tags: c#, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a Method in a C# Application from a Webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535675/run-a-method-in-a-c-application-from-a-webpage)

I would like to host a webpage with Buttons, txtbox, etc and when User Clicks a button, it runs a method on the C# application. Also the App can gather the Data from the webpage's txtbox.

The Application is located on the user computer. It needs to send and receive Information from the Host. (My Web Host) I have full access to the server. It basically just needs to send and receive simple bools, strings, ints... and for the Website (accessible from anywhere, Mobile phone for example) to have controls that can run Methods on the Application actually running on the computer. So far, I am able to upload and Download from the server via FTP (The app edits 2 html files, and a .txt file)

I appreciate any advice you can give. Thank you

Comment: Please don't simply post the same question over again. If it's been closed as being too general/vague to answer, re-posting it with no editing or further details is not going to help you.

Comment: You really need to be more explicit about what you are trying to accomplish.  Quite honestly, I am having a difficult time understanding exactly what you are trying to do.  So there's an app on the user's box? Is this a web app?  Again, you'll need to be more clear.

Comment: @djacobson The other was closed before I could elaborate. I edited it, and then noticed that it had already been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have an .ASPX web page that controls a WinForms (traditional Windows application) - for example, the user clicks 'Close' and your WinForm app would close (just an example).

To do that you would need to run some sort of inter-process communication, of which there are a number of choices.  Prior to .Net 3.0 you would typically use .Net Remoting which has been replaced by [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) (WCF) as of .Net 3.0.

Comment: Thank you. You understand what I'm trying to do. This seems to be what I need. I am working with .net 3.5, so this should work fine. I guess I have some reading to do now. If you know of any code samples, I would be glad to see. Thank you for your post.

Comment: Why dont u just set up a webpage that acts like a settings-file? Set up a timer and grab the sourcecode from the url. Loop through your code and get ur settings / commands what ever.